# Possible to render points plotted in Python with Matplotlib using a blending mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, gis

I'm plotting a series of overlapping points of various sizes using `matplotlib` in order from largest to smallest (smallest on top) but I am wondering if it is possible to configure the points to draw using a `soft light` blending mode so that you can see through stacks of points without using alpha blending.

I'm loading my data using `pandas` and then plotting using the `pandas` plotting function (which uses `matplotlib`) like this simplified example:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

roads = gpd.read_file('roads.shp')
points = gpd.read_file('points.shp')

f, ax = plt.subplots()

roads.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=.5, color='#2D1B1B', zorder=1)
points.plot(ax=ax, column='color', markersize=size, zorder=2)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

---

## Here's how the plot looks:

(I have exaggerated the overlap)

[image: Solid Color Points]

---

## Here's how I would like it to look:

In this example each point is blended using [a soft light blending mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Soft_Light), which makes it possible to 'see through' each point a bit without desaturating or adding transparency to points which are overlapping white. This makes it easy to see the larger, darker colored circles in the middle, without making the smaller, lighter colored circles on the white background harder to see the way alpha blending would.

[image]

---

## Difference from Alpha Blending:

The most common method for blending overlapping points like this is to just make them transparent so that the overlapping points add up to a more intense color, but while this is desirable for visualizing density, it does not make sense in this context and looks washed out and bad:

[image]

---

Is it possible to plot points using a soft light blending mode in `matplotlib`?

Comment: So pretty. I would like to know how you load the basemap as I can't see it from the code above.

Comment: There's not actually a basemap loaded at all, I simply plot [`TIGER/LINE` shapefiles from the census bureau](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html) to give the viewer a minimal reference point without detracting from the data; that's the `points = gpd.read_file('points.shp')` and `roads.plot( . . . )` lines above.

Comment: can you elobrate the code ?

Comment: (For reproducibility, it would be useful to link to the files you use directly in the question. Also how did you produce the second image?) This is indeed an interesting problem, but I fear it cannot be done with matplotlib (or anything that is based on it like geopandas) because this blending would need to take place when rendering the graphics and none of the currently available matplotlib renderers have this kind of option.

Comment: https://github.com/anntzer/mplcairo (a custom matplotlib rendering backend I wrote) now implements (as of master) Porter-Duff and PDF blending modes (among which soft light).  As there is no support from Matplotlib itself, currently you need to use custom artists that will set the blending mode operators accordingly, see https://github.com/anntzer/mplcairo/blob/master/examples/operators.py for an example.