# Avoiding overlapping opacities in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I want to plot two non-opaque lines that intersect each other, you get a region of higher opacity in the region where they intersect:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([-1, 1], [0, 0], 'k-', lw=10, alpha=0.5, zorder=1)
plt.plot([0, 0], [-1, 1], 'k-', lw=10, alpha=0.5, zorder=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this, and have the intersection region also have the exact same color and opacity as the rest of the lines?

Comment: Afiak, this can't be done in easily in matplotlib, although it would be a nice capability. I think it would be called a "blending mode", but if you search for it you can find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285019/possible-to-render-points-plotted-in-python-with-matplotlib-using-a-blending-mod) where the upshot is, you can do it by doing the math on the images yourself in numpy, or use the cairo backend with some complications (see the linked comments). Depending on exactly what you want to do, you might make something work with `fill_between`.

Comment: So, currently the best solution is to plot all the lines as opaque, rasterize the subplot somehow and then blend it yourself with the other layers?

Comment: I think it depends on exactly what you want. To do the plot you show (without the dark patch), I think I'd go with `fill_between`. Overall, I'm not sure what you really want since your question seems to embody a contradiction: The entire point of transparency is to see a thing behind another thing, but here you're saying you don't want to see the thing behind the other. That's a "blending mode" that's easy to do -- just make things not transparent. So when I say `fill_between` I'm picking and choosing aspects of your question so it makes sense to me, but it's also hard to generalize.

Comment: @tom10 There is no contradiction. Think of this as layers in Photoshop. Essentially, I want to draw an arbitrary number of lines/shapes on a layer -- and then apply an alpha/opacity to the entire layer. Transparency here is not being applied as a blending mode individually for each shape, but is applied at once to the union of all shapes/lines. Making two transparent lines was the simplest toy example I could come up with to make a post.

Answer (score 0):

I think [tom10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102302/tom10)'s comment is pretty accurate but you could maybe do an admittedly ugly workaround where, since you have to know the values going in before plotting, only plot up until the intersection and then proceed to plot the intersection as a different line so it looks the same as the rest of the lines.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a toy example. The use case is an arbitrary number of lines (in all sorts of orientations - not only vertical/horizontal), unknown at the beginning to the user.

Comment: In order to plot, you have to pass an array, no? And then generate lines? Based on those calculations you can remove intersections, I think it would be pretty computationally heavy though. I think `fill_between` will do what you want as tom10 said. He is right that it is kind of the point of transparency to allow the intersection, so it's not surprising there isn't a function for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue using ax.axhspan / ax.axvspan.

```
ax.axvspan(min(x), max(x), facecolor=colors_dict[levels[0]], alpha=0.5)   
ax.axhspan(min(y), max(y), facecolor=colors_dict[levels[0]], alpha=0.5)
```

For my current usecase it is sufficient to choose lighter colours and move the areas to the back by setting `'alpha=1'` and `'zorder =-10'`.

Left: original, Right: pseudo-solution
[image: original problem]      [image: pseudo solution]

But I am afraid, it won't be a solution for long as I expect to need transparent plotting with some other areas later on. So a actual feature, as mentioned in the post linked above by @tom10, would be useful.

Answer (score -1):

The intersection is due to the alpha variable in the plot, I have also crossed this problem. I solved it by creating the same instance and coloring it to the background hence it works as a screen for the top layer. For every layer on top create an extra layer with the background color.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([-1, 1], [0, 0], 'k-', lw=10, alpha=0.5, zorder=1)

# The alpha is increased to 1 and the color is changed to the background color
plt.plot([0, 0], [-1, 1], 'white', lw=10, alpha=1, zorder=1)

plt.plot([0, 0], [-1, 1], 'k-', lw=10, alpha=0.5, zorder=1)
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: The problem with this method is that it completely defeats the purpose of using opacity. The white line is no longer opaque. So, if there's something behind the intersecting lines, you don't see it anymore.